# How can I change position of instantiate objects (clones)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, initialization, position, scale

I created a series of sphere clones in my game. After that I adapted the scale so that they appear smaller. However, now there is a gap between these spheres ... and I would have to change the position of this instatiate game objects. I changed my code already exactly at this position but nothing happens. So please I need your help! How can I do this? I would have very small spheres which are located near together.

Here the code:

```
using UnityEngine;  
using System.Collections;    

public class SineWave : MonoBehaviour {


     private GameObject plotPointObject;
     private int numberOfPoints= 100;
     private float animSpeed =1.0f;
     private float scaleInputRange = 8*Mathf.PI; // scale number from [0 to 99] to [0 to 2Pi] //Zahl vor Mathf, Anzahl Bön 
     private float scaleResult = 2.5f; // Y Achse Range 
     public bool animate = true;




     GameObject[] plotPoints;


     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {

         if (plotPointObject == null) //if user did not fill in a game object to use for the plot points
             plotPointObject = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere); //create a sphere


         //add Material to the spheres , load material in the folder Resources/Materials 
         Material myMaterial = Resources.Load("Materials/green", typeof(Material)) as Material;
         plotPointObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material = myMaterial;


         //change the scale of the spheres 
         //plotPointObject.transform.localScale = Vector3.one * 0.5f ;
         plotPointObject.transform.localScale -= new Vector3(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f);


         plotPoints = new GameObject[numberOfPoints]; //creat an array of 100 points.
         //plotPointObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().material =Material.Load("blue") as Material


         //plotPointObject.transform.localScale -= new Vector3 (0.5F, 0.5F, 0.5F); //neu: change the scale of the spheres


         for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++)
         {
             plotPoints[i] = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(plotPointObject, new Vector3(i -
(numberOfPoints/2), 0, 0), Quaternion.identity); //this specifies
what object to create, where to place it and how to orient it

         }
         //we now have an array of 100 points- your should see them in the hierarchy when you hit play
         plotPointObject.SetActive(false); //hide the original

     }
```

Thank you already in advance!

Edit: 
As I said in the comment I achieved now to place my spheres without a gap in between. However, as soon as I animate my spheres (with a sine wave) there is still that gap between the spheres. How can I adapt this? Should I copy the code of the Start function in the Update function?

I would be very happy to get some help. Thank you very much!

```
enter code here void Update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++)
    {
        float functionXvalue = i * scaleInputRange / numberOfPoints; // scale number from [0 to 99] to [0 to 2Pi]
        if (animate)
        {
            functionXvalue += Time.time * animSpeed;

        }




        plotPoints[i].transform.position = new Vector3(i - (numberOfPoints/2), ComputeFunction(functionXvalue) * scaleResult, 0); 

        //print (plotPointObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ().bounds.size.x);


        // put the position information of sphere clone 50 in a vector3 named posSphere 
        posSphere = plotPoints [50].transform.position;


    }

    //print position of sphere 50 in console 
    //print (posSphere);
}


float ComputeFunction(float x)
{
    return Mathf.Sin(x);  
}




}
```

Comment: This isn't C, did you mean C++?

Comment: You are right. The code is written in C#.I choose C# for the tags but as soon as I update the tags it is written C++. No idea why...

Comment: if you know size of the objects you can simply add value. For example you only want to place objects horizontally, in Y up z front world you can only add initialposition + i*objectSize.

Comment: I do not see what you mean, sorry. Can you give me an example. And where in the script I have to change this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could make the Barış solution.
For each new object that you are instantiating, you will set his position to the lasted instantiated position adding the size of the object itself, or whatever distance that you want they have from each other.

```
var initialPosition = 0;
var distanceFromEachOther = 20;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++) {
    var newPos = new Vector3(initialPosition + (i * distanceFromEachOther), 0, 0);
    plotPoints[i] = (GameObject)GameObject.Instantiate(plotPointObject, newPos, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

That will make a gap between the spheres at `X` pivot, depending on their size. Change the `distanceFromEachOther` var, adjusting for your needs.

You could also get the object distance with `plotPointObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds.size`, so `distanceFromEachOther` could be, for example `distanceFromEachOther = plotPointObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds.size.x + 5`. So then you will have the objects with a perfectly distance of 5 from each other.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works with the second methods you suggested. The problem now is, as soon as I animate all that in a sine wave in the void update function, the gap is still there. Do I have to copy the code of the start update in the void update?

Answer (score 0):

give this a try:

```
Transform objectToSpawn;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPoints; i++)
{
    float someX = 200;
    float someY = 200;
    Transform t = Instantiate(objectToSpawn, new Vector3(i -(numberOfPoints/2), 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as Transform;
    plotPoints[i] = t.gameObject;
    t.position = new Vector(someX, someY);


}
```

Comment: I think I should do this in the Start Update function? Why can I change the appearance of my spheres when I switch off the update function so that all my spheres are well aligned. However, as soon as I animate my sine wave with all that spheres, there is again that gap between the spheres.